# Unable to get datawindow group trailer and summary to slide up

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder, datawindow

I have

1. a report with grouping.
2. some items displayed on the group trailer band
3. an autosized datawindow in summary band
4. a footer band

A run of the report brings 5 rows of data returned in the report's detail band.

The problem is, the report displays 4 rows of data on the first page then automatically puts the last row of the data on a second page along with the group trailer band and the autosized datawindow in the summary band.

I think this is due to the associated row of the grouping mentioned in the following.
http://pbbraindump.wordpress.com/2008/05/25/groups-and-grouping/

So essentially there are 4 rows of data, followed by a large empty space in page 1, followed by 1 row of data on the second page + trailer + summary.

I've tried setting "Slide Up" on all of the items in the trailer group and the summary datawindow but it does not slide up to make the report 1 page even when it looks like there is enough space on the printed report.

Why does it not slide up? Can it be forced to slide up?

Comment: Not really, the slide feature is flaky sometimes probably something there that you don't see or columns are too wide but it will slide if there's really nothing in the way.  There's a setting on the columns and the bands not sure if thats what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the 'Autosize height' on all of the bands?

Comment: yes, I have tried setting that on all bands. That and all bands and objects have been set to slide up all above. The objects still do not slide up to fill the empty space

Comment: Update: deleting the autosized datawindow in the summary band seem to allow everything to slide up after that. The datawindow in the summary band isn't so large that it won't fit in one page though.